# Add line numbers to beginning of every line in a file using C

Tags: c

I am working on an assignment that reads a text file and adds a line number at the beginning of each line.

I'm pretty new to coding so I'm sorry if this is a simple task. The code that I've written will give me an output tell me how many lines are in the file, but I cannot figure out how to actually make it number the lines and show them to me.

```
//lineNumber = 1;
//Open the file
//While ((c = read a character) is not EOF)
//    If (c is \n)
//        Print "lineNumber", then increment it
//    Print c
//End while
//Close the file
//
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
void main() {

    int ln = 1;
    char c;
    FILE *fp = fopen("text.txt", "r");

    while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF) {

        if (c=='\n'){
            ln++;
        }
    }
    printf("lines num: %d",c);
    fclose(fp);
    //return 0;
}
```

Example Input:

```
This is a text file
This text file has words in it.
```

Example Output:

```
000001 This is a text file
000002 This text file has words in it.
```

Comment: `printf("lines num: %d",c);` why are you passing the character in the file (`c`)? You want to pass the `ln` variable here.

Comment: If you’re processing lines, use `fgets()` (or POSIX `getline()`) to read whole lines (make sure the buffer is big — 4 KiB is about right). It’s then trivial to print line numbers at the start of a line.  Failing that, keep a track of column number: print the line number after reading a character when the column number is zero, then increment the column number.  When you read newline, reset the column number to zero after printing the character.

Comment: I would tackle this with the `fgets()` function, but which might not read a whole line. If the input string has a final newline it is a whole line or the last part of a broken line so then you would increment the line number. The final line of a textfile might not end with a newline, but that won't matter because there won't be another line number to print.

Comment: Is the pseudo-code at the top of the file what was given to you by the teacher as the way to implement this?

Comment: @ChrisWhite — the pseudo-code is buggy: it doesn't print the line number for the first line of output.

Comment: Agreed, but we don't want to suggest something (fgets) that might not be part of the assignment.

Comment: I would *not* process whole lines.  You don't need to.  You only need to read one character at a time.  Start out by writing "00001".  Then read one character at a time and print it.  (Use getchar, not fgets).  If that character is a newline, print the next line number.  Also, don't try writing back to the same file.  Put all your output in a different file, and then rename the file at the end.   (Or (IMO preferrably) do no file manipulation at all: read stdin and write stdout.  Do all the file manipulation in the shell when you call your program.)

Comment: yeah fgets it totally unneccessary, putchar() of putc() is sufficient and that's probably already been learned. printing to stdout may be sufficient, check the wording of the assignment. modifying input is messy and makes testing harder.

Comment: Note that a line can end in 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x0A 0x0d, 0x0D 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C if the text is in ASCII, and  0x85, 0xE2,0x80,0xA8 (0x2028) or 0xE2,0x80,0xA9 (0x2029) if it is encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: @some, assuming that the above code correctly counts the number of lines, dealing with unicode is probably not needed.  also those code points seem to relat to "document formatting" rather than "text files".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a large number of small problems to address. First, unless you are using a non-conforming compiler, the conforming declarations for `main` are `int main (void)` and `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (which you will see written with the equivalent `char *argv[]`). See: [C11 Standard §5.1.2.2.1 Program startup p1 (draft n1570)](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.2.1p1). See also: [What should main() return in C and C++?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/)

Next, `c` must be type `int` not type `char` to match `EOF`, e.g.

```
    int c, last = 0; /* c must be type int, not char to match EOF */
```

Don't hardcode filenames or use *magic-numbers*. Either pass the filename as an argument to `main()` or prompt for it within your program. You can conveniently take a filename to open or read from `stdin` by `default` with the ternary operator as follows:

```
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;
```

Finally to your code, since you want to *Prefix* each line with the line number, you must output the line number for the first line *Before* you output the characters for that line (and the same for each subsequent line). You can do that simply by outputting the number first (using the `"%06zu "` conversion specifier with the modifiers `'0'` to output leading zeros and the *field-width* `6` to match your format shown). Also note the type for your `ln` counter is changed from `int` to `size_t`, the recommended type for counters in C (you can't have a negative line-count).

Putting this together with the use of the `last` character to allow checking for the `'\n'` before outputting your characters, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    int c, last = 0; /* c must be type int, not char to match EOF */
    size_t ln = 1;      /* use size_t for counters */
    /* use filename provided as 1st argument (stdin by default) */
    FILE *fp = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : stdin;

    if (!fp) {  /* validate file open for reading */
        perror ("file open failed");
        return 1;
    }
    printf ("%06zu ", ln++);            /* output line 1 number */
    while ((c = getc(fp)) != EOF) {     /* read each character */
        if (last)                       /* test if last set */
            putchar (last);             /* output all characters */
        if (last == '\n')               /* test if last is newline */
            printf ("%06zu ", ln++);    /* output next line number */
        last = c;                       /* set last to c */
    }
    putchar (last);                     /* output final character */
    if (last != '\n')                   /* check POSIX eof */
        putchar('\n');                  /* tidy up with newline */
    if (fp != stdin)                    /* close file if not stdin */
        fclose (fp);

    return 0;
}
```

(**note:** the check of `if (last != '\n')` after exiting the loop checks for the presence of a POSIX line ending on the last line, and if not, you should manually output a `'\n'` so that your program is POSIX compliant)

**Example Input File**

```
$ cat ../dat/captnjack.txt
This is a tale
Of Captain Jack Sparrow
A Pirate So Brave
On the Seven Seas.
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/linenos ../dat/captnjack_noeol.txt
000001 This is a tale
000002 Of Captain Jack Sparrow
000003 A Pirate So Brave
000004 On the Seven Seas.
```

Look things over and let me know if you have further questions.

(**also note:** if your compiler does not support the `zu` conversion specifier for `size_t`, remove the `'z'` and output as an unsigned value - VS10 or earlier do not support `zu`)

Comment: lets hope the compiler will unswitch the `if (last)`

Answer (score 4):

you've got a program that counts the number of lines in the file, you need to change that so that instead of displaying the count at the end you need to 
echo the contents of the file

(eg using `putchar(c);` after each getc()) and

each time you see a `\n`  (and also at hte start of the file)
you need to print a number with leading zeros and then a space.
`printf("%06d ",ln) ;` is probably what you want for that.

Answer (score 0):

To number the lines, or to change any part of the file for that matter, it is best to load the file into memory as a string, manipulate that string (in this case, add line numbers) and then create a blank new file. Copy the modified string into the new file, and then rename it to the path of the old one, so as to overwrite it.

```
/* fp: File whose lines are to be numbered 
   pathOld: Its path */
void giveLineNos(FILE *fp, const char *pathOld)
{
    char line[MAXLINE]; /* line that is read in */
    char numbered[MAXLINE + 8]; /* line that will include its number */
    int i;

    char tempName[L_tmpnam];
    tmpnam(tempName);  /* generate filename guaranteed to be unique */

    FILE *fpNumbered = fopen(tempName, "w"); /* create temporary file onto 
                              which we will write; error checking omitted */

    for (i = 0; fgets(line, MAXLINE, fp) != NULL; ++i) {
        /* write out the line number followed by its contents */
        snprintf(numbered, MAXLINE + 8, "%d: ", i + 1);
        strcat(numbered, line);

        fputs(numbered, fpNumbered); /* save line to file */
    }

    rename(tempName, pathOld);  /* rename the temporary file to that of 
                                    the old one, thereby overwriting it */
    fclose(fpNumbered);
    fclose(fp);
}
```

If you want only to print the numbered lines without even touching the file, then you replace the `fputs` statement in the above code with a call to `printf`:

```
/* fputs(numbered, fpNumbered); */ printf("%s", numbered);
```

(putting a newline after the `%s` is wrong because `fgets` already puts a newline in the `line` buffer, which is then transferred into `numbered`.)

Also note that your `main` is non-standard. Use `int` as the return type, not `void`.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend against incrementing the line count with each `'\n'` and instead increment the line count each time a character was read *after* a `'\n'`.  That is also when code should print the line number

```
unsigned long ln = 0;
int prev = '\n';
int c;  // Use int here, not char
while((c=getc(fp))!=EOF) {
  if (prev == '\n'){
    printf("%06lu ", ++ln);
  }
  putchar(c);
  prev = c;
}
if (prev != '\n') {
  putchar('\n');  // print a \n for input that lacks a final \n
}
printf("lines num: %lu\n", ln);
```

Notice the above works well when there are 0 lines (no data) and when the input does not end with a `'\n'`.

A common weakness of using `fgets()` is 1) when line length exceeds the input buffer, special handling is needed 2) when input unexpectedly contains a *null character*, which fouls tropical *string* handling.  `getchar()` does not have those problems.